# Proof that A is the disjoint union of two sets, one contained in a set B and one disjoint from a set B

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

This is my first post here so please be gentle. I tried to find an answer to this and couldn't find anything this specific so bear with me if I didn't search hard enough.

Can you tell me if this proof makes sense? Have I made any assumptions that mess everything up? Your input is greatly appreciated.

> **If A and B are two sets, then prove that A is the union of a disjoint pair of sets, one of which is contained in B and one of which
>   is disjoint from B.**
>
> **Proof by Cases:**
>
> **Case 1:** A ∩ B = ∅
>
> **Case 2:** A ∩ B ≠ ∅
>
> Case 1: Suppose A ∩ B = ∅. Let a1 ∪ a2 = A such that a1 = ∅ and a2 =
>   A. Then a1 ⊆ B and a2 ∩ B = ∅. Then A is the union of two sets, one of
>   which is contained in B and one of which is disjoint from B.
>
> Case 2: Suppose A ∩ B ≠ ∅. Let a1 ∪ a2 = A such that a1 = A ∩ B and a2
>   = A - B, so a1 ∩ a2 = ∅. Then A is the union of two sets such that a1 is contained in B and a2 is disjoint from B.
>
> Thus, if A and B are two sets, then A is the union of a disjoint pair
>   of sets, one of which is contained in B and one of which is disjoint
>   from B.

Is this right? Is there an easier way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Okay, so clearly this can be much easier. As simple as

> Let A = a1 ∪ a2 such that a1 = A ∩ B and a2 = A ∩ Bc. Then a1 ∪ a2 =
>   ∅, a1 is contained in B and a2 is disjoint from B.

Comment: Have you drawn a Venn diagram?

Comment: Why do you need two cases? Show that $A \cap B$ and $A \cap B^c$ satisfy the requirements.

Comment: @Bungo And THAT is what I meant by easier. Thank you!

Comment: be careful disjoint union has another meaning.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes.

Comment: Consider $A\cap (B \cup B^c)$, use distributive law, then consider your cases.

Comment: An easier way: Let $C=\{x:x\in A\land x\in B\}$ and $D=\{x: x\in A\land x\not \in B\}.$ There are no separate "cases" to consider